# c# sql stored procedure isn't committing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, commit

Whenever I run the following code I get the expected output

```
private int NewBorrower(string givenName, string surname)
{
    int returnValue = 0;
    using (conn)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "AddBorrower";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@givenName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = givenName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = surname;
        SqlParameter id = cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
        id.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            returnValue = (int)cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", e.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

When run from the front end I get the results I want, but when I check the database it doesn't show up in the table.

For good measure this is also the stored procedure being used

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddBorrower]
    @givenName nvarchar(50),
    @surname nvarchar(50),
    @id int = NULL OUTPUT
AS
    INSERT INTO llBorrowers (givenName, surname)
    VALUES (@givenName, @surname);
    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
RETURN @id
```

I've tried using transactions on both the c# and sql sides, and that didn't work at all.
I should also mention that it is a local database, but I'm not sure that should affect it.

Comment: Are you looking at the right database? Also if you're using those deprecated user instances with a .mdf file and it's included in your project with "copy to output directory" set to true then that copy will overwrite the one in the bin folder each time you build your project.

Comment: How do I set it to false if this the problem? I don't know where that setting is.

Comment: Well if you've got the .mdf included in your project click it in Solution Explorer and push alt+enter (at least that's what it is for "General Development") and you should see the item properties appear

Comment: I tried that, it did not fix the problem.

Comment: But you are using user instances? I.e. AttachDbFileName?

Comment: I don't believe I am.

Comment: As @ta.speot.is says in its first comment. What database are you looking at? Are you using Server Explorer to check the results? If yes, are you using the same connection in the Server Explorer and in your code?

Comment: Yes I am using the same connection. The first thing I did was check that I was using the same connection string.

Comment: Could you please **show us** the connection string you're using - thanks!

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data\LocalLibrary.mdf;Integrated Security=True
Apologies, looks like I am using user instances. i.e. AttachedDbFileName etc

Comment: And your server explorer connection string is?

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="D:\Local Library\LocalLibraryApplication\LocalLibraryApplication\Data\LocalLibrary.mdf";Integrated Security=True
Essentially the same thing, but the Data Directory is extended

Comment: No, it is not the same. Check your BIN\DEBUG\DATA folder, you will find an MDF there

Comment: Okay, well then would you be so kind as to tell me why the record I'm adding still isn't showing up in the database file that is located in bin\Debug\Data?

Comment: Added something to my answer below

Answer (score 2):

When you use the DataDirectory substitution string in a WinForms application, its real value changes depending on your debug or release configuration.

In DEBUG your DataDirectory points to PROJECTFOLDER\BIN\DEBUG (or x86 variation if it is the case).
So it is extremely easy to get fooled by this. You create a connection in server explorer but this connection is ignored by your code that works on a different database.

You could create another connection in Server Explorer and name it DebugConnection, still keeping the original one for schema changes while you use the DebugConnection to check if your code executes as expected

As a side note, keep particular attention to the property `Copy To the Output Directory` property on the MDF file if it is listed between the project items. If you set it to `Copy Always` every time you start a debug session a fresh copy of your db will be copied from the project directory to the output directory effectively destroying the updates executed by your code. I recommend to set it to `Copy Never` and handle manually the database schema changes

A reference: [Where is DataDirectory](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-?forum=sqlce)

Comment: +1 for saying "you need to look at the right database and not overwrite it each time..." in as many words as you did.

Comment: @ta.speot.is yes even my wife says I am too verbose :-) (no kill-off switch provided here)

Answer (score -1):

You may try creating a SQLTransaction in C# part

Also, try changing your code like -

```
//Just create a SQL connection - cmd = new SqlCommand(conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "AddBorrower";
```

Comment: @CyanideGiraffe - Try the above solution

Comment: I tried creating a transaction, however it didn't work. Secondly, I have already set the command text when I initialised the object. See lines 9 and 10

Comment: Remove setting command text from there - add it as in the answer above. Also, can you debug and see what is the value of returnedValue

Comment: The stored procedure is running. It is returning the number 2. As this would be the next logical ID as there is only on record in this table.

Comment: Are there any triggers defined on llBorrowers ?

Comment: There are no triggers