# Access DB, No reaction from the DB

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, syntax

Encountered with a problem... maybe something in the syntax of the query,
and the compiler doesn't throw any Exception.
But the table do not receive information.

Anything you noticed that maybe wrong?

```
OleDbConnection conn;
OleDbCommand cmd;


public Commands(OleDbConnection con)
{
    conn = con;
}


public Commands()
{
    conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB.accdb");
}

public void node_Join(int id, byte[] mac)
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Nodes ([J_ID],[Node ID],[Node MAC],[Line Quality],[Status]) values('" + Convert.ToString(id) + @"',0,'" + BitConverter.ToString(mac) + @"',0,'Join')", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your connection string is right? What are the values of `Convert.ToString(id)` and `BitConverter.ToString(mac)`? Why do you think you should have these `Commands` methods? What are the types of your columns? And you should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Types: J_ID -> Number, Node ID -> Number, Node MAC - > String, Line Q -> Number, Status -> String.          right now im just learning to work with sql and etc. so parameterized queries not so needed.

Comment: cue little bobby tables...

Comment: DataDirectory? [Where is DataDirectory](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-?forum=sqlce)

Comment: DataDirectory is Main folder of the project.

Comment: Duplicate of these other questions involving `Copy Action` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074944/c-sharp-sql-stored-procedure-isnt-committing/21075358 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202659/database-properties

Comment: Found the problem, thanks to [ta.speot.is][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/users/242520/ta-speot-is

Changed the "|DataDirectory|" in the the connection string to full path.
Worked like charm.

Anyway thank everybody...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `|DataDirectory|` you just have to understand what it does.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you try to do and I feel like taking a risk to answer but anyway..

As I said in my *[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215864/access-db-no-reaction-from-the-db#comment31951895_21215864)*,  you should always use [*parameterized queries*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

And since your `J_ID` column is `Number`, there is no point to insert it a string with  `Convert.ToString(id)`. Using `id` (I assume it is an integer) will probably fine.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection`.

Try like this;

```
using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB.accdb"))
{
  using(cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Nodes ([J_ID],[Node ID],[Node MAC],[Line Quality],[Status]) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?", conn))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nodeid", 0);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nodemac", BitConverter.ToString(mac));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@line", 0);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Join");
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Also think Steve's suggestion in *[his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215864/access-db-no-reaction-from-the-db#comment31952049_21215864)*.

Comment: Same problem. The table is still empty.

Comment: @VictorLev Updated my answer. Can you please try **only** my code and let me know it is working or not?

Comment: Found the problem, thanks to


http://stackoverflow.com/users/242520/ta-speot-is

Changed the "|DataDirectory|" in the the connection string to full path.
Worked like charm.

Your code is working perfectly and much more comfortable ... thanks for helping.

Comment: *Also use using statement to dispose your OleDbConnection* OleDbCommand is IDisposable too, because it's a DbCommand. Also conn.Close is redundant.