# Entity Framework SaveChanges is not working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a C# winforms application, and a SQL Server `.mdf` database file.

I tried to use Entity Framework. It works great when retrieving data from the database, but on calling `.SaveChanges()` nothing happens. No error, no exception, and no changes saved.

This issue just drives me crazy. I found a bunch of questions with nearly the same issue, but neither of the answers apply to my case.

My code looks like that:

```
using (World_ParkingEntities context = new World_ParkingEntities())
{
   client _client = context.CreateObject<client>();
   _client.name = name;
   _client.mobile_number = phoneNo;
   _client.email = email;
   context.AddToclients(_client);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

My connection string:

```
<add name="World_ParkingEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\World_Parking.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Read my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215864/access-db-no-reaction-from-the-db#comment31952206_21215864

Comment: I saw a lot of comment from you... which exactly one you meant?

Comment: Can you please show us your **connection string**? Also: when you add the entity using `.AddToClients()`, then there's really no need to do the next two lines (getting entity state and manually setting it to `Added` - the entity state will already be `Added` anyway!)

Comment: You are right, I also thought that this line is unnecessary, I added it as part of my trials.
I edited the question above, please review

Answer (score 3):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint after the `context.SaveChanges();` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `World_Parking`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=World_Parking;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Comment: Does it mean that my DB will be located locally on the server I worked on?

Comment: To use `.mdf` you need a SQL Server instance anyway - no other way to do this. And it would be a lot easier to actually create the database **on that server instance** upfront, instead of using the flawed (and deprecated) `AttachDbFileName=` approach